# Error in File *****.rpt: The table could not be found. in crystal reports C#

Tags: sql, sql-server, winforms, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I am a newbie in programming.
I just created a small app using C#.NET with externally designed crystal report(v 9.0).
The crystal report has TWO DATA SOURCES in two different servers (But both are SQL SERVER 2008 R2 s). 
FYI - When the external report runs separately it prompts twice for entering login info.

Now I integrated it with my code as below.

```
 private void PrintVoucher() 
    {

        int varvoucherno;
        ReportDocument rptDocument = new ReportDocument();


        TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        Tables CrTables;

        TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos2 = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo2 = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo2 = new ConnectionInfo();
        Tables CrTables2;



        rptDocument.Load(@"K:\PRIDER_VOUCHER_V2.rpt");



        varvoucherno = 2014090005;




              ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions;
            ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition;
            ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
            ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();


            crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = varvoucherno;
            crParameterFieldDefinitions = rptDocument.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
            crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["VOUCHER_NO"];
            crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

            crParameterValues.Clear();
            crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
            crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);



            PRIDER_STATEMENT.Transactions objtrans = new Transactions();


            conn = new SqlConnection(objtrans.sqlstring);
            cmd = new SqlCommand("PRINT_VOUCHER", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@VoucherNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = varvoucherno;


            SqlParameter pararetvalueout = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int);
            pararetvalueout.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            conn.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();




            crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "SERVER_IP_1";
            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "DB_1";
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
            crConnectionInfo.Password = "*****";

            crConnectionInfo2.ServerName = "SERVER_IP_2";
            crConnectionInfo2.DatabaseName = "DB_2";
            crConnectionInfo2.UserID = "sa";
            crConnectionInfo2.Password = "*****";

            CrTables = rptDocument.Database.Tables;

            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
            {
                crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
                crtableLogoninfo2 = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                crtableLogoninfo2.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo2;
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo2);
            }










            rptDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);






    }
```

I am getting following error with it.

```
DataSourceException was unhandled.

Error in File PRIDER_VOUCHER_V2 {CF71142D-5D36-4121-A854-BCA381FA9B67}.rpt:
The table could not be found.
```

Please help me. I'm in a very needy situation.

Comment: I believe the error message already clarified the problem clearly. A table needed in the .rpt file doesn't exist in your database.

Comment: hi @Sim, I used same code in a previous report that contain only one data-source and works perfectly. But in here there are two data source connections. I couldn't understand why it is happening. Is this the correct way of building connection objects for two data sources.(foreach loop code block)